# Which sentence is grammatically correct?

Tags: prepositions

I need to say that something is of the same material as ash but not in a phrase. I'm looking for a short adjective and noun combination. Which of these two is correct?

> homogeneous **to** ash

or

> homogeneous **with** ash

Comment: Which 'ash'? If it's the wood, use the noun attributively. If it's one of the 'substance left after burning / volcanic eruption' group, it usually wouldn't be homogeneous anyway. What would be 'exactly like ash'? Wouldn't this **be** ash?

Comment: it is in a literature context. some boy is compared to ash like he is of the same material. I need the title for the story. it is in Persian. so a word for word translation would be 'homogeneous to ash' at least thats what I have figured out. please help me find the most appropriate translation.

Comment: *The Boy of Ash? The Ash Boy? The Boy Made of Ash? As If of Ash? The Boy of Ashes? The Ashes Boy?*

Comment: no no no. I literally want to say 'homogeneous with ash'. is this correct gramatically? or should i say 'homogeneous to ash'?

Comment: forget the story and the boy. I need to say 'of the same material as ash) BUT in a muc shorter phrase!

Comment: 'Made of frogs and snails and puppy-dogs' tails' is grammatically correct, and in fact a well known expression, but would never be used in serious conversation.

Comment: is this sentence correct? this pen is homogeneous to ash.

Comment: We use the word 'homogeneous' to mean 'uniform throughout' - so a homogeneous mixture is a mixture where the components that make up the mixture are uniformly distributed throughout the mixture. It isn't homogeneous to or with anything, it  **is** homogeneous.

Comment: This is not a problem of grammar but of semantics. _Homogeneous_ simply isn't used with that meaning. You should find a different word to get across the meaning you want.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is founded on an unconventional use of the word “homogeneous.”

Comment: so according to what you say it is impossible to say in English that something is exactly of the same material as ash? like I am --- to ash? i cant use other synonyms because I have to use homo- and material in one word, so the only existing word is homogeneous. and you sir say I cant use it as an adjective.

Comment: Why can't you use other synonyms? This explanation makes no sense.

Comment: @Hamed: If you have some substance **X** that "is exactly of the same material as ash", then it **is** ash. If it's not actually ash, but is of some material which can be treated as ash for your specific purposes (fertiliser, perhaps?), then you could perhaps say it's **ash-compatible** or **ash-like**.

Comment: @Hamed, regarding “is this sentence correct? this pen is homogeneous to ash”:  No, that is not a correctly-formed sentence; it misuses the word homogeneous, or uses it nonsensically.

Comment: @Hamed You might be thinking of "homologous". In which case: "homologous with" was more common before 1980, and "homologous to" has been more common since 1980. Choose the one you like better.

Comment: come on guys :( use some imagination. the context is literature, actually the title of a short film! not chemistry or biology terms. it is both imagination and fact that we are all 'homologous to ash'. that I wanted to be the title. now do  you find it a good title or should I use other words?

Comment: (1) Your concept is wrong. You wouldn't say 'The beach is made from the same material as sand' - it _consists of_ sand. _Sand_ is a mass noun denoting the basic material (an impure compound). _Ash_ is similarly in this usage a mass noun denoting a material (a pretty heterogeneous and variable mixture in this case). (2) I can't think of a single word (+ _of_ maybe) meaning 'made from the same substance as'. Except 'consubstantial' - and I'd not use that here. (3) The only acceptable expression in this area is probably the metaphorical 'Ashes to ashes; dust to dust'.

Comment: Please never just ask “Which is correct?”  It shows no effort on your part, and gives us nothing to go on.  As [the Help Center says in its “How to ask a good question” section](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask):  **“Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!”** Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

*Homomorphic* (with alternate spelling *homeomorphic*) may be the word you are seeking.  According to [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/homomorphic) it means  “Of or pertaining to homomorphism; having a homomorphism”, a homomorphism being “A structure-preserving map between two algebraic structures”, but less generally one can think of a homomorphism as a bijective (that is, both injective and surjective) correspondence between two things.  Thus, to say “X is homeomorphic to ash” is to say that X  corresponds directly to ash.

Comment: The problem is that if you only took Latin and not Greek, you end up thinking it means man-shaped. :)